# Is there a way to check what NFSv3 exports clients are mounting?

Tags: linux, nfs

Is there a way to see from the server which clients have an NFS (v3) export mounted?

I thought that `showmount -a` would show this information but it doesn't seem to be the case. It does appear to show a list of connected clients but it doesn't show which exports they have mounted.

The server is running SLES 10.

The output of `showmount -a` I get is (some similar lines removed for privacy purposes):

```
All mount points on oneose:
10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22,netboot.cluster.example.com:/mnt/foo
10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22,netboot.cluster.example.com:/mnt/project/foo1
10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22,netboot.cluster.example.com:/mnt/project/foo2
10.0.0.0/8:/mnt/home
10.128.1.2:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.0.65:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.128.0/22:/mnt/project
10.2.128.10:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.128.30:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.128.30:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.128.40:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.128.40:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22,netboot.cluster.example.com
10.2.128.50:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.10:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.10:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.11:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.11:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.12:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.12:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.13:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.13:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.14:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.14:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.15:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.15:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.16:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.16:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.17:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.17:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.18:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.18:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.19:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.19:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.20:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.20:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.21:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.21:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.22:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.22:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.23:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.23:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.24:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.24:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.25:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.25:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.26:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.26:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.27:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.27:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.28:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.28:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.29:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.29:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.30:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.30:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.31:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.31:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.32:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.32:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.33:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.33:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.34:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.34:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.35:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.35:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.36:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.36:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.37:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.37:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.38:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.38:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.39:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.39:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.40:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.40:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.41:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.41:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.42:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.42:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.43:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.43:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.44:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.44:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.45:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.45:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.46:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.46:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.47:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.47:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.48:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.48:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.49:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.49:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.50:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.50:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.51:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.51:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.52:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.52:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.53:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.53:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.54:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.54:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.55:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.55:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.56:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.56:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.57:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.57:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.58:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.58:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.59:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.59:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.60:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.60:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.60:10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.61:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.61:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.62:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.62:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.63:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.63:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.64:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.64:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.65:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.65:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.65:10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.66:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.66:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.66:10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.67:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.67:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.68:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.68:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.69:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.69:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.70:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.70:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.71:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.71:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.72:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.72:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.73:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.73:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.74:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.74:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.75:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.75:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.76:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.129.76:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.77:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.78:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.79:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.80:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.81:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.82:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.83:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.84:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.85:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.86:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.87:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.88:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.89:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.129.90:10.0.0.0/8,10.2.128.0/22
10.2.16.208:10.0.0.0/8
10.2.16.222:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.0.249:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.0.67:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.1.6:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.128.10:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.128.20:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.129.1:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.129.2:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.129.3:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.129.4:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.16.216:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.11:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.12:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.1:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.3:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.4:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.5:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.6:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.7:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.2.9:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.11:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.12:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.13:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.14:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.15:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.16:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.17:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.18:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.19:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.1:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.20:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.21:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.24:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.26:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.27:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.28:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.29:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.2:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.30:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.32:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.33:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.34:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.35:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.36:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.37:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.38:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.39:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.3:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.40:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.41:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.4:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.5:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.6:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.7:10.0.0.0/8
10.3.3.8:10.0.0.0/8
10.4.0.10:10.0.0.0/8
10.4.0.14:10.0.0.0/8
10.4.0.6:10.0.0.0/8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On linux:

```
showmount -d <server IP>
```

will show what directories a client has mounted (as long as rpc.mountd has a record of them, anyway)

Comment: I want to see from the server which directories all clients have mounted. I'd rather not have to go to every client and see what it is mounting from the server.

Comment: There's not a reliable way to do that AFAIK.  NFS is stateless by design (stateless from the server perspective, that is).

Comment: That said, you may have a rmtab floating around on your server.  That will likely have some stale entries in it.

Answer (score 0):

`Showmount -a` works for me, showing a list of `hostname:/export/path` pairs.  At least, it does when querying our NetApp toaster.  What type of NFS server are you looking to get this information from?

Comment: Added more details to the question.